# Getting QGIS to import data?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, import

The shapefiles I was sent did not contain a .prj file, and instead came with these .xml files that seem to be the equivalent of the projection file. QGis does not seem to 'read' these XML files when I import the associated shapefiles, and results in the imported polygons being totally out of place and out of scale.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <coordinateSystem>
        <name>Universal Transverse Mercator - Zone 51 (N)</name>
        <datum>World Geodetic 1984 (WGS84)</datum>
        <system>Transverse Mercator</system>
        <unit>Meter</unit>
        <majorAxis>6.378137000000000000000000e+006</majorAxis>
        <eccentricity>8.181919084262148600000000e-002</eccentricity>
        <centerX>0.000000000000000000000000e+000</centerX>
        <centerY>0.000000000000000000000000e+000</centerY>
        <centerZ>0.000000000000000000000000e+000</centerZ>
        <rotationX>0.000000000000000000000000e+000</rotationX>
        <rotationY>0.000000000000000000000000e+000</rotationY>
        <rotationZ>0.000000000000000000000000e+000</rotationZ>
        <scaleAdjustment>0.000000000000000000000000e+000</scaleAdjustment>
        <scaleX>9.996000000000000400000000e-001</scaleX>
        <localScaleX>1.000000000000000000000000e+000</localScaleX>
        <scaleY>9.996000000000000400000000e-001</scaleY>
        <localScaleY>1.000000000000000000000000e+000</localScaleY>
        <falseEasting>5.000000000000000000000000e+005</falseEasting>
        <localOffsetX>0.000000000000000000000000e+000</localOffsetX>
        <falseNorthing>0.000000000000000000000000e+000</falseNorthing>
        <localOffsetY>0.000000000000000000000000e+000</localOffsetY>
        <centerLat>0.000000000000000000000000e+000</centerLat>
        <centerLon>1.230000000000000000000000e+002</centerLon>
    </coordinateSystem>
</data>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could manually create your own PRJ file using a text editor, all the information you need is there. Just use any existing PRJ as a template.

Alternatively, open the shapefile in QGIS, assign the correct projection (right click, properties, general), then save/export as a new shapefile, being sure to select the correct CRS when you do this.

Comment: you can look it up on epsg.io or spatialreference.org and download the .prj file

Comment: Is there a way to import this as a custom CRS in QGIS? I'm not quite sure how to write down the other variables in the .prj such as scalex and y.

Comment: No need, it is a standard CRS already loaded in QGIS (and every other GIS software ever, I would imagine). ESPG: 32651

Comment: Also, you won't need to include everything in the XML file in the PRJ, just fill in whatever was there in the template PRJ you are using